# Csv to json by the same key-python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have a big csv file (aprx. 1GB) that I want to convert to a json file in the following way:

the csv file has the following structure:

header:  `tid;inkey;outkey;value`

values:

```
tid1;inkey1;outkey1;value1
tid1;inkey2;outkey2;value2
tid2;inkey2;outkey3;value2
tid2;inkey4;outkey3;value2
```

etc.

The idea is to convert this csv to a json with the following structure, basically to group everything by "tid":

```
{
"tid1":  {
    "inkeys":["inkey1", "inkey2"],
    "outkeys":["outkey1", "outkey2"]
         }
}
```

I can imagine how to do it normal python dicts and lists, but my problem is also the huge amount of data that i have to process. I suppose pandas can help here, but I am still very confused with this tool.

Comment: 1gb isn't very big. Have you actually run into performance issues? This doesn't sound like a job for pandas to me.

Comment: What did you try so far ? Did you write some code on a small csv ? We can help you optimize your code / understand your errors, but you have to work a bit by your own !

Comment: Hint: try to create this same structure in python dictionary, should be a simple task.

Comment: Are the `tid` values "grouped" - i.e. can you be certain that once you go from `tid1` to `tid2` in the file, there will be no more occurrences of `tid1` along the way? 

If this is the case, you could just read the file line by line, compose a dict, and append to JSON once the `tid` changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to use `pandas` and read your csv into a dataframe. Say the csv is saved in a file called `my_file.csv` then you call

```
import pandas as pd    
my_df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
```

Then you need to convert this dataframe to the form that you specified. The following call will convert it to a `dict` with the specified structure

```
my_json = dict(my_df.set_index('tid1').groupby(level=0).apply(lambda  x : x.to_json(orient = 'records')))
```

Now you can export it to a `json` file if you want

```
import json
with open('my_json.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(my_json, outfile)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this should be straight-forward to do with standard Python data structures such as `defaultdict`. Unless you have very limited memory, I see no reason why a 1gb file will be problematic using a straight-forward approach.

Something like (did not test):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv 
import json

out_data = defaultdict(lambda: {"inkeys": [], "outkeys": [], "values": []})
with file("your-file.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f):
    for line in reader:
        tid, inkey, outkey, value = line
        out_data[tid]["inkeys"].append(inkey)
        out_data[tid]["outkeys"].append(outkey)
        out_data[tid]["values"].append(value)

print(json.dumps(out_data))
```

There might be a faster or more memory efficient way to do it with Pandas or others, but simplicity and zero dependencies go a long way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pandas with `groupby` and a dictionary comprehension:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

mystr = StringIO("""tid1;inkey1;outkey1;value1
tid1;inkey2;outkey2;value2
tid2;inkey2;outkey3;value2
tid2;inkey4;outkey3;value2""")

# replace mystr with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(mystr, sep=';', header=None, names=['tid1', 'inkeys', 'outkeys'])

# group by index
grouper = df.groupby(level=0)

# nested dictionary comprehension with selected columns
res = {k: {col: v[col].tolist() for col in ('inkeys', 'outkeys')} for k, v in grouper}

print(res)

{'tid1': {'inkeys': ['outkey1', 'outkey2'], 'outkeys': ['value1', 'value2']},
 'tid2': {'inkeys': ['outkey3', 'outkey3'], 'outkeys': ['value2', 'value2']}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other `defaultdict()` answer:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

with open('file.txt') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        tid, inkey, outkey, value = line.strip().split(';')
        d[tid]['inkeys'].append(inkey)
        d[tid]['outkeys'].append(outkey)
        d[tid]['values'].append(value)
```